# R replace single backslash to double backslash

Tags: r, backslash

How can I convert from single backslash `\` to double backslash `\\` in R

For example :

```
\\\server\\folder1\\sub_folder -> "\\\\\\\server\\\\folder1\\\\sub_folder"
```

Comment: Are the backslashes inside a string variable? Or are they sitting in your text editor/console? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The user enter an input in R shiny text area looks like : \\folder1\subfolder1\werwr , and i want to change each \ to \\

Answer (score 1):

```
# What your input should look like.
txt <- "\\\\server\\folder1\\sub_folder"
cat(txt) # prints \\server\folder1\sub_folder

# Replacing the backslashes for double backslashes.
txtNew <- gsub("\\", "\\\\", txt, fixed = TRUE)
cat(txtNew) # prints \\\\server\\folder1\\sub_folder
```